# Advice on best software to catalogue sections of individual audio files

Tags: database, cataloguing

I have around 20 hours of individual field recordings. I need to catalogue each file, up to around 30 mins long, creating a database of the different sections of each recording. Any advice on the best software to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify your work environment? For example, what is OS are you use?

Comment: I am on a Mac, using Big Sur